# The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$' in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

here am trying to keep excel sheet data in to data set.help me to over from this error
The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
        Dim ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim RecTab As Data.DataTable
        Dim RecTab1 As Data.DataTable
        Dim Rectab2 As Data.DataTable
        Dim ds1 As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim HFCell As String
        Dim HTCell As String
        Dim FilePath As String

```
    HFCell = "A1"
    HTCell = "B1"
    m_FileName = "Data.xls"
    FilePath = Server.MapPath("..\TankGauge\Data_Mgr") & "\" & m_FileName
    Try
        Dim connectionString As String = ""
        Try
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + FilePath + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
            MyConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            MyConnection.Open()

            dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

            ds = New Data.DataSet
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
            RecTab = ds.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
```

Comment: What version Excel file is it?  Is it XML?

Comment: Ms office 2007(.Xls) and it is not xml

Comment: Ah not sure then.  However, here's the connection string I use which works for me: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"`

Comment: @MounikaReddy The xls format cannot be accessed by Jet.OLEDB.4.0 So you need to use Ace.OLEDB.12.0 as Mike said.

Answer (score 0):

In your Excel workbook, is there a worksheet named Sheet1? If not, rename the sheet or change your code to call out the sheet you want to get data from.

Comment: yup my excel has the same name i checked already even it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

I believe the database driver you're using won't work.  Try changing:

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + FilePath + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
```

to:

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + FilePath + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
```